# Direct sum in $C[-1,1]$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

(a) Show that the vector space $X$ of all real-valued continuous functions on $ [-1,1] $ is the direct sum of the set of all even continuous functions and the set of all odd continuous functions on $[-1,1]$

(b) Give examples of representations of $ R^3 $ as a direct sum
i) of subspace and its orthogonal complement
ii) of any complementary par of subspaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(b) is easy enough and you should be able to do it. For (a), do you know the identity
$$f(x) = \frac{f(x) + f(-x)}{2} + \frac{f(x) - f(-x)}{2}?$$